# Entity Framework Core Where clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework Core to query a view. I can add where clauses to columns in the view, but when adding a clause to one particular column, it seems it is adding null checks.

Entity Framework Core version : 3.1.4

Example:

```
var query = _appContext.MyView.AsQueryable();
query = query.Where(d => d.field1 != d.field2);
```

This produces something like this:

```
Expression = {value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[DAL.Models.MyView]).
WHERE ((([e].[field1] <> [e].[field2]) OR ([e].[field1] IS NULL OR [e].[field2] IS NULL)) AND ([e].[field1] IS NOT NULL OR [e].[field2] IS NOT NULL))
```

But it should just be :

```
WHERE ([e].[field1] <> [e].[field2])
```

Comment: I'm assuming both fields are nullable? IF so, does `query = query.Where(d => d.field1.Value != d.field2.Value);`

Comment: Yes, both fields are nullable. I tried adding .value to both fields with the same results. I was previously using a dbml file and this same code worked. I'm not sure why the null checks are being added now.

Comment: @Dennis Which database are you using and what exact type are `field1` and `field2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that comparing a value against NULL will result in NULL (depending on the database and operator used). As an example, the MySQL documentation [12.3 Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html) says:

> If one or both arguments are `NULL`, the result of the comparison is `NULL`, except for the `NULL`-safe `<=>` equality comparison operator. For `NULL <=> NULL`, the result is `true`. No conversion is needed.

But when you have `WHERE NULL` for a row, it will not be included. This can mean that when you compare `'abc' != NULL` you will not get this row even though the values `'abc'` and `NULL` are different.

Assume you have the following table:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM foobar;
+----+--------+--------+
| id | field1 | field2 |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 | NULL   | NULL   |
|  2 | NULL   | a      |
|  3 | a      | a      |
|  4 | b      | a      |
|  5 | b      | NULL   |
+----+--------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

When you run a simple `field1 != field2` condition, you get fewer rows than expected (as seen from the original C# code, not from the database standpoint):

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM foobar WHERE field1 != field2;
+----+--------+--------+
| id | field1 | field2 |
+----+--------+--------+
|  4 | b      | a      |
+----+--------+--------+
```

As you see the rows with the id `2` and `5` are not returned. To get these rows as well, EF Core will add the additional checks/operators to get all the rows you expect:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM foobar WHERE ((field1 != field2 OR field1 IS NULL OR field2 IS NULL) AND (field1 IS NOT NULL OR field2 IS NOT NULL));
+----+--------+--------+
| id | field1 | field2 |
+----+--------+--------+
|  2 | NULL   | a      |
|  4 | b      | a      |
|  5 | b      | NULL   |
+----+--------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So, that EF Core will generate this kind of query is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Core seems to behave differently than using a enfityframework (dbml file). You have to put checks in for a value first which I didn't have to do before.

This worked.
Code:
query = query.Where(d => ((d.field1.HasValue && d.field2.HasValue) && d.field1!= d.field2.Value));

Answer (score 0):

This situation is clearly described in official documentation and how to disable that also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/null-comparisons

```cs
optionsBuilder.UseRelationalNulls();
```